How to rewrite index.php?arg=test to /index/test/ in nginx
In nginx, how can I rewrite index.php?arg=test to show as /index/test/ in my browser?
currently, all I have is
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        }

Which lets me do /index/?arg=test and /?arg=test
But I can't figure out the rest.
Even better would be rewriting index.php?arg=test&arg2=test2&arg3=test3 to /index/test/test2/test3/
Thanks
I tried all sorts of things I found online, such as https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-rewrite-url-rules
But it always says wrong variable or something. In general, solutions don't really have anything to do with what I want specifically, or they are wrong. So basically, I don't know what to do.
Thanks

Just to be clear, your application is outputting URLs such as /index/test/, right? You understand that that's not Nginx's responsibility.

No, I have index.php?page=abc&subpage=def and I want the URL in the browser to look pretty like /index/abc/def.

It is your responsibility as the application developer to create these URLs, not Nginx's. It is Nginx's responsibility to handle these requests.

I am not going to rewrite a whole php script myself just because I don't like how the URL looks.

invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.com:35 referring to this line from the digitaloceans example             rewrite user.php?id=$1 ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ break;

I'm unclear on your previous comment. Are you saying "thanks for the information, but never mind because it isn't worth the effort", and we can close this? Or are you saying "no, I don't want to do that, I want to fix this with Nginx only"

I am saying the application is there and I need a way to make pretty URLs for it. It doesn't matter how, but obviously I can't rewrite it from scratch.

Your application is ultimately outputting HTML such as <a href="https://example.com/index.php?z=x">. That's you, you are stating a fact. If/when someone clicks, the browser will put that in the address bar. That's just how the web works. Links in your HTML go to the address bar. If you want, you can then instruct Nginx to perform a 301/302 HTTP redirect for all of these, but you need to tell Nginx where each should go. Commonly this is to a single router script such as index.php. But short of redirects on every URL, there isn't a way for Nginx to solve this problem.

If you look at every modern CMS with "pretty URLs", you will see that they do it this way. It is the responsibility of the CMS (the application) to create these pretty URLs, and the server (Nginx, Apache, IIS, etc.) to route them back to a PHP script. But they must exist before the server
